# C++ error in a custom queue: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, queue, runtime-error

I'm trying to create a generic queue class based off a custom vector. My code runs fine in the sense that it outputs everything I want it to given my input, and doesn't crash. However, if I call my `queue.pop()`, I get the following as the program finishes executing:

```
a.out(6878) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb210403981: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

My vector is built around an array of type T, declared `T * typeArray;`. All `queue.pop()` does is call a function from my vector, `vector.pop_front()`. The line that seems to be causing the problem is

```
// Assign the pointer to the second position in the array. 
typeArray = &typeArray[1];
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't this work? Thanks!

Comment: You don't show enough code. Show your generic queue class. And what's wrong with `std::deque`? Compile with all warnings and debugging information (`g++ -Wall -g`), learn to use the `gdb` debugger and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: It will be impossible to answer this without some illustrative code. But as an aside, I would suggest using an `std::deque` instead of an `std::vector`. Removing elements from the front of a vector is inefficient. If you look at `std::queue`, it uses `std::deque` by default.

Comment: Your code is not working and you expect a diagnosis from **one** line of code? I would guess that the problem is exactly what the error message says. The pointer you are freeing is not the same as the pointer you allocate, because you are incrementing that pointer in pop_front. I also suspect you have more problems with your code than you realise (maybe that's why you are reluctant to post it). But again in the absence of more code that is only a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only allowed to `delete` a pointer that was returned to you by `new` (the same principle holds for `malloc` and `free`).

Once you replace the original pointer with

```
typeArray = &typeArray[1];
```

it's an error to

```
delete [] typeArray;
```

You need to maintain separate pointers for the allocated storage and for the queue's head.